# Debian 7 doesn't notify me about security updates

Tags: gnome, debian-wheezy

On a fresh install of Debian 7, GNOME isn't telling me when I need to install updates.  It's not even checking for updates automatically (`apt-get update`).  Manually running `apt-get update` doesn't produce a notification, even if log out & in again.  But `apt-get upgrade` definitely shows outstanding security updates!  What's going on and how can I keep my desktop secure?

---

If I update the system manually, I can still reproduce this problem on demand.  (Just downgrade a package e.g. using Synaptic and Package->Force Version; you can log out & in to give the notifier a fair chance at spotting it.  E.g. I found bash can be downgraded and then needs a security update.  Obviously *don't downgrade bash if you're running any vulnerable servers, OR on an untrusted network due the DHCP bash hook vulnerability*).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known bug [#757989 No update notifications - Debian Wheezy 7.6](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=757989). 
 The previous `update-notifier` package is still available.  So the workaround is `apt-get install update-notifier`.

Make sure to run `update-manager`, click Settings, and check the Update tab shows daily updates as expected.

Personally I also enable "Download automatically", so the updates are quicker when I do them.

> GNOME-PackageKit would be responsible for showing a notification about
>   new packages, but the GNOME Design-Team didn't like that behaviour. So
>   GPK won't show anything at time. Later, this will be changed so
>   security updates are shown. On GNOME, new packages will be installed
>   during restart, but I am not sure yet that we should use this feature. -- [#710355](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=710355#10) (I know Fedora Linux uses this upgrade on restart option).

---

UPDATE for Debian 8: I and others are still having the same problem (I believe this is widespread).  I'm pretty sure it's getting fixed in Debian 9, which is great but I don't want to run that while it's in  the testing/unstable stage.

There's a better workaround in Debian 8.  You just have to install a single package, which is available in jessie-backports.  http://blog.tenstral.net/2015/09/update-notifications-in-debian-jessie.html